# Why use private methods in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I recently took over development of a relatively mature WPF MVVM project that didn't have a lot of unit tests. So once I understood what most of the code was doing I thought it'd be a good idea to write some more.

Now, I don't have much experience of either MVVM or WPF but it seems obvious that given the relatively limited, property-based binding between the UI and the code, a lot of the logic can be locked away behind private methods. That's what I'd have done, and that's what my predecessor had done.

Unit Testing private methods is a bit of a pain (I do know how to use PrivateObject, but it's clumsy), and reading around discussion on the subject there seemed to be a fair number of people evangelising for the decreased use of private methods to facilitate testing.

So that got me thinking: the primary reason for locking things behind private methods is so other developers using the object don't get overwhelmed by near-useless methods, right? But in WPF MVVM you're invoking the objects from the XAML, where there's limited intellisense and you need to know the names of what you're calling before you do so.

So ... is there any good reason for using private methods when coding in this paradigm? Or, given that one of the key benefits of MVVM is increased testability, is it perhaps better to leave things public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View model in MVVM is really a type of facade over the model that can be bound to the view so the view does not have a direct coupling to the model.  It provides view specific types and interfaces like ObservableCollection, INotifyProperyChanged, ICommand, etc.  XAML can't bind to anything private that I'm aware of.  I would tend to take what I think you're describing as private members and place them in a physically different class (or classes) that I would classify as the "model".  **(update start)** Typically if that sort of thing is private, it's *business logic*. (if it's used by the view--ala commands--they need to be public).**(update end)**  That could be tested independently from the view model.

I think you'll find that once you do that you won't have many tests on the view model, as you'd really just be testing framework elements like ObservableCollection, or whether interfaces are implemented correctly. And in order for the VM to use the model, its members will need to be public and thus testable.

**update:**
To be clear, there's nothing wrong with "logic" in the view model--just as long as that logic supports the view (or something else that does) directly.  e.g. Commands.

Comment: I think you are giving the view models not enough credit. One great example of private members are the backing methods of commands (Execute and CanExecute). A command is a wrapper around the *logic* of the command and prevents execution of the Execute without a valid CanExecute. 

Another good example are events that respond on services that are actively providing data (think of a GPS location service or an accelerometer service). You can then update (public) properties based on the events coming from the services.

Comment: I wouldn't call ICommand implementations "business logic"--so, I feel I've given VMs credit in that respect.  What those command implementations call (in terms of business logic) should be external to that ICommand implementation and the VM, IMHO.  The receipt of the events should be done outside of the VM and should be "bound" (not data binding) in a decoupled way so that the information can flow back to the VM--when needed (lots of good examples of that around).  Direct coupling from a background event source like GPS service to a view never leads to goodness.

Comment: Of course a command *might* forward the logic to a service, based on the goal of the command. If it is to remove an item from a list of items contained by the VM, the logic is perfectly valid inside the VM. I never said it was *business* logic, I said logic ;-). I don't see why an additional layer to push members required by a specific view from a service require an additional abstraction (or decoupling) layer. How would you put the GPS service / view model communication in an MVVM architecture? Imho that's where the VM is for.

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik Agreed on the *logic* in the VM/command.  I thought I had mentioned "business logic" in my answer--I'll correct.  Background communication with a service I'd put outside of the VM and the VM would couple to that itself.  Examples of where that is more important is when GPS events come in when the view is unloaded.  If the VM decouples on the view unload, you don't have a problem if service events come in after that... (there's no guarantee "unsubscribing" from events like that stops them right away)

Comment: Depends on the framework you use ;-). In Catel the view model is Initialized when the view is loaded and Closed when the view is unloaded. This gives you are very good way to subscribe / unsubscribe in a solid way without having to worry about "ghost view models". That's why I think a service can be injected in the VM, then subscribe in Initialize, unsubscribe in Close and you are good to go. But glad that we are on the same page, I probably mistunderstood your post the first time I read it.

Comment: The problem is that some of these services can still send events *after* unsubscription as it likely happens asynchronously (more likely that it was queued to send before unsubscription).  Coupling to a more transient object like a view increases the likelihood of race conditions like that.

Answer (score -1):

To me the private members is the way to ensure encapsulation. This is a big enough reason to use them whenever possible.

As regards to Intellisense in XAML - it was never particularly useful, once you step out of XAML-Codebehind world. Due to the way how Views are connected to ViewModels no editors (ReSharper, VS) are capable of supporting it and probably never will. Imagine a child VM loaded dynamically - best you can do is trust that your property paths are valid. So whether public or private XAML can't cop on. This compliments private members.

PrivateObject is by all means a hack, but it's delivers what I need, allowing me to keep my VM protected against unpredictable usage of private members.

Comment: fyi, these attributes are pretty awesome. They allow you to define the type of view model that your designer should user for 'intellisense' and the binding creator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor - you cant get quite far with those but in order to support dynamicly loaded views you'll have to write your own framework...

Comment: Other than private backing fields to support properties, what *should* be "encapsulated" in a View Model that is effectively a "value converter" or a data structure?